# Save command to linking into network button on form

Tags: sql, ms-access

this is taking to long for me to figure out but i need a button or a link that when the form is filled out and when i click the save button it prompts me to save the file into our network or server.

is there a way i can link this up or use a code that links or saves the form into our system?

Comment: maybe this can give you an idea https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/909411-can-i-use-docmd-outputto-export-current-record-only

Comment: and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111510/exporting-ms-access-form-results-to-excel

Comment: Save what file? Do you mean record? You don't save form, you save data. Save into what system? What database is data saved into?